# OBD returns different number of commands supported everytime I run it

Tags: python, obd-ii, elm327

I am using [python OBD library](https://github.com/brendan-w/python-OBD) and every time I run `connection_to_obd = obd.OBD("/dev/rfcomm0", baudrate=38400, protocol="5", fast=False)` even with auto protocol to establish a connection this happens [7 commands supported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnSC4.png) or [45 commands supported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WHpd.png).

Why does it work sometimes and others not?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your application / library timeout waiting for a full response expires too soon. The protocol search should be allowed to complete before the response is parsed for supported PIDs/ Best way to do this is to wait for the '>' for the ELM based devices.